# SignalR Hub Multiple Client Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

This is something I'm not sure about, if anyone can help.

Say I have a SignalR Hub class and it has a Dictionary as a member.
One of the Hub methods receives a string as a parameter, uses that as a key and updates part of the corresponding value in the Dictionary.  This could include add/removing the dictionary item.
In my scenario there could be 100's of "simultaneous" calls to this Hub method.

My question is.  Do I have to lock the Dictionary whilst the update is being done?  OR does SingalR only run one copy of the method at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the direct answer to your question, but you could use a concurrent dictionary to be safe

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have tried a ConcurrentDictionary.  Sometimes it's methods are not as convenient to use as locking a standard Dictionary and I assume it has similar overhead.